# npm ERR! node-sass@4.14.1 install: `node scripts/install.js`

Tags: npm, sass

When I have downloaded node-sass of npm package I have came across the error below. I investigated but I didn't find any solution. Have you any of idea?
I have tried installing previous version but didn't work

```
$ npm i node-sass@4.14.1
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported

> node-sass@4.14.1 install C:\Users\gokha\OneDrive\Masaüstü\can-project\BurakConstructureProject\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

internal/fs/utils.js:307
    throw err;
    ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, read
    at Object.readSync (fs.js:592:3)
    at tryReadSync (fs.js:366:20)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:395:19)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1090:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\gokha\OneDrive\Masaüstü\can-project\BurakConstructureProject\node_modules\request\index.js:18:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30) {
  errno: -4048,
  syscall: 'read',
  code: 'EPERM'
}
npm WARN burakconstructureproject@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.14.1 install: `node scripts/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.14.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\gokha\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-27T12_36_18_529Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have the same problem!

Comment: @Jono unfortunately I have not found